# Is bootloader required to run a firmware?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, bootloader, rtos

I am currently working on firmware for a Stellaris ARM microcontroller board and I am running the SYS/BIOS RTOS.

I was wondering if the bootloader is required on the board when I upload my firmware onto it. Can I overwrite the bootloader on the flash with my .bin file, or am I required to offset my start address to preserve the bootloader.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the general case (i.e. not specific to Stellaris), software is software, the bootloader is software, your application is software, the processor cannot tell the difference so quite evidently a bootloader is not required, the software that runs at reset could as easily be your software.

However the obvious benefit of a bootloader is the ability to apply in-field updates without connecting special equipment; you might regret loosing that capability.

Some chips (again generally, check your data sheet for Stelaris specifics) have a bootloader in mask ROM rather than Flash and you cannot delete or overwrite that, but usually configuration pins can be set to select the boot behaviour in order to by-pass the bootloader for example.

Comment: Yes, after a bit of research and trial on my board I came to the same conclusion. The bootloader is only required if the firmware needs to be updated by attachments like ethernet or serial. For my stellaris board, the there were two bootloaders that allowed me to update using serial and ethernet. In general, a JTAG interface can be used to upload firmware and the bootloader would not be required.

Answer (score 1):

No you can use jtag and dont need running software in order to stop and re-flash the firmware.